# Probability that two people have the same birthday in a party?

Tags: probability

I remember the birthday problem as a kid, and it was what got me into loving mathematics even though I didn't understand the solution at the time.

I was thinking about the problem and I thought that I found a solution but it turned out to be wrong even though I couldn't find out way.

My wrong solution:

So I thought of the problem as numbered balls in an urn.

We have 2 balls numbered randomly a number from 1 to 365.

We randomly choose 1 ball named A.The probability that A has the same number as another ball B is $\frac{1}{365}$ and the probability that A has the same number as C (the ball left) is also $\frac{1}{365}$. And the probability that B has the same number as C is $\frac{1}{365}$.

Thus the probability that two balls have the same number in $\frac{\binom{total}{2}}{365}$

Simplifying the formula we get:

Probability that two in a party have the same birthday is: $\frac{0.5(n^{2}-n)}{365}$

But the formula seems to be wrong compared to solution I found of the problem, but why? And how can I calculate the probability without having to calculate the probability of that they are different(like how many solution solve this problem)?

Comment: The events are not independent.  Knowing for example that mike and john have the same birthday and that john and fred have the same birthday tells us something about whether or not mike and fred do.

Comment: Note also, for $n\gg 300$ your "probability" is greater than one and couldn't possibly have been a probability.

Comment: when an event is so likely its probability is 2 @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz but i am calculating the probability that any two have the same birthday.

Comment: @JMoravitz I know it is wrong but i fail to know why and how to correct it.

Comment: are you computing the probability that at least two people have the same birthday?

Comment: Do you believe your formula if n = 3?  Trying that case would be my suggestion.

Comment: @CJD yes, that is why i use combination

Comment: @JMoravitz taking into consideration A being different than B will increase the probability that it would be the same as C. Thus my solution should (if this was the case) give a lower number not a higher one.

Comment: What you're calculating is actually the expected number of pairs of people sharing a birthday - which is strictly greater than the probability that there is at least one pair.

Comment: What's the justification for adding the (1/365)s together?

Comment: My advice would be to think about the case n = 3 and there are only 3 numbers instead of 365 numbers.  I think in your case your formula would say the probability is 1 that two of the balls would have the same number, but definitely that's not right.  I think the mistake you're making is in adding together the probabilities.

Comment: [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Me too!

This is how I do it.

Let's find the probability that no two people have the same birthday.

We have $\displaystyle \frac{365}{365} \times \frac{364}{365}...\frac{365-n+1}{365}$

Because each person must have a new birthday.

Therefore, the probability that two people do have the same birthday is $1-\displaystyle \frac{365}{365} \times \frac{364}{365}...\frac{365-n+1}{365}=\boxed{f(n)=1-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{365-k}{365}\right)}$

If this isn't what you're looking for, then just comment.

Comment: What is the index in your product?  Surely you want the $ n $ inside the parentheses to be different than the $ n $ outside on the limits

Comment: RIGHT. my bad!!! fixed @JMoravitz