# How many people do you need for the probability that two have the same birthday to exceed 50%?

Tags: probability

This question is similar to [Probability that two people have the same birthday in a party?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327984/probability-that-two-people-have-the-same-birthday-in-a-party), but I'm interested in solving for $n$. The formula phrasing this question would be, I believe,

$$1-\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\frac{k}{365})\ge0.5$$

but how do I solve this for $n$?

Comment: Just calculate it at successive integers until you get above the threshold.

Comment: One way to do it is to realise that the left hand side is monotonically increasing and goes from 0 (when $n=1$) to 1 (when $n=366$). So you only need to check a finite number of cases. In particular you need to find an $n$ such that the left hand side is smaller than $0.5$ if you insert $n$ and $\geq 0.5$ if you insert $n+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is equivalent to $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\frac{k}{365})\leq\frac{1}{2}$, and the value of the left side decreases as $n$ increases (and reaches $0$ as $n\geq366$), the most precise way to do is to evaluate the value of the left side as $n=1, 2, \cdots$.

But since the calculation is complicated, here is an adhoc way one can use: for $|x|\ll1$, it holds $1-x\approx e^{-x}$, thus the inequality can be adjusted to $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{-\frac{k}{365}}\leq\frac{1}{2}$, or $\exp({-\frac{n(n-1)}{730}})\leq\frac{1}{2}$. This is equivalent to $n(n-1)\geq730\log2$, and if you know the value of $730\log2\approx505.99$ by solving inequality in the range of positive integer you will acquire $n\geq23$, which gives a same result as the first method.

Comment: The only thing is that it is not _a priori_ obvious that $n << 365$.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments and at http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.birthdayprob.html, the way to do it is to just try out different $n$ till you get one that satisfies the criterion. (I thought there might be a way to get a closed-form solution, but apparently there isn't).